# How do I find time complexity of while loops?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I am designing a simple algorithm to be used at hardware level. And I want to find its time complexity.

```
i=1
while(i<=n)
{
    i=i*2;
}
```

## How I'd go about finding time complexity of this?(And I'm wrong).

i=1,2,4,8....n
=$2^{n-1}$

So the time complexity is $2^n$

But I am wrong according to the professor. Why? Isn't my mathematics correct.

Comment: I have not the slightest idea where you got 2^(n-1) from. You wrote literally n = 2^(n-1). I only goes up to n. But you didn’t do n calculations. How often did you double I? Write the exact steps down for n = 1024.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity is dependent on the number of times the while loop loops. Since the value of i is increasing exponentially, the number of loops will be logarithmic.

- If the value of n=1, then the loop count = 1.
- If the value of n=2, then the loop count = 2.
- If the value of n=4, then the loop count = 3.
- If the value of n=8, then the loop count = 4.
- and so on

The pattern in general is that loop count = lg(n)+1, where "lg" is read "log base 2", which means that the asymptotic time complexity is O(lg(n))

See for yourself with the following python code snippet:

```
def main():
    i = 1
    loop_count = 0
    n=8

    while i <= n:
        i = 2*i
        loop_count = loop_count+1
    
    print("loop_count = " + str(loop_count) + " when n = " + str(n))

main()
```

As an exercise for yourself, can you determine the asymptotic time complexity if i is increasing by 3 * i; that is, i = 3 * i?

Comment: I've not understood it fully, but I suppose it's lgn/lg3?

Comment: @barnyard9 Let me know what you're still having trouble with, and I'll try to assist.

Comment: @barnyard9 Also, if you meant log base 3 of n, then you're correct. It would be represented as log(n)/log(3), but you need to use log base 10 for that; that is, not the log base 2.

Comment: You're a good man sir. Thank you. Can you guide me towards some good books/videos on this subject?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-fourth-Thomas-Cormen/dp/026204630X/ref=sr_1_1?crid=CVQPD5BXV0QF&keywords=introduction+to+algorithms&qid=1701851190&s=books&sprefix=Introduct%2Cstripbooks%2C60&sr=1-1

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-analyse-loops-for-complexity-analysis-of-algorithms/

Comment: Introduction to Algorithms is a standard computer science textbook that goes in-depth into the subject. The geeksforgeeks is a good resource in general, but the particular link goes over the loops.